# Do I need to parse an entire XML file to modify one line?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have an XML file that has a single value I would like to have changed by the user. This is basically the Description value, which I will have stored in a text box on the UI.

The XML is literally the second line within the file, and is within the `<description>` `</description>` tags.

Would I need to have my application parse the entire file prior to editing that line, or is there another way I could do this? Note the application is coded in `VB.NET` and uses `.NET 4.0`. I'd like to keep it within 4.0 if at all possible, as I can guarantee my users have the 4.0 framework installed. My question is whether or not I should parse the entire file to get at that one node, or is there an alternative way to handle this?

Comment: If you can absolutely guarantee that the `<description>` will always be the second line within the file, then no, you don't have to parse the file at all. Just input the file line by line, and copy most lines to an output file, but omit the second line and instead output `<description>New description</description>`.

Comment: Tacking onto that, if you parse/traverse it using System.Xml.Linq's XDocument and XElement, it should be relatively easy/fast to work with (not to mention more reliable).

Comment: Building it line by line wouldn't work, as the entire file's length is 1500 lines or so. Well, it'd work but it'd probably be a huge amount of effort. It sounds like using Linq's XDocument and XElement will be the easiest way to do it after all.

Comment: Whether the file is 15 lines or 15 million, whether you parse it as XML or input/output by lines, you'll probably have to have your program go through the whole file. I'm not sure why you think going line-by-line is a huge effort, but using XML tools to process XML is almost always the right answer (much more robust).

Comment: XML lines are variable-length records. In general, it is impossible to modify variable-length-record data formats except by copying what's before the section to be changed, then the change, then what's after the section to be changed. That's just the nature of continuous files. If you want to store your data in a database of some form, that will often let you modify a single record... and there are XML-aware databases... but basically that's the same operation as parsing it and modifying it and serializing it back out, you're just doing the parsing and serializing separately.

Comment: It should be pretty trivial to modify a SAX "copy XML semantically" program to recognize the one element you want to alter and swap in the new contents.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the XML, then one solution is to move the `<description>` element into an external parsed entity. You can then modify this entity without changing (or reading) the rest of the XML.